# Monitoring Dataflow pipelines with Datadog

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, datadog

I'm looking for a solution to monitor GCP Dataflow pipelines with Datadog to extract the built in metrics as well as Beam custom metrics. Currently Datadog offers integration for other GCP services, but not for Dataflow. Has anyone done similar work and can share pointers how to build this as custom solution?

Comment: does Datadog collect data from Stackdriver? If so, you should be able to look at the metrics published by Dataflow into stackdriver...

Answer (score 2):

For now I see only two possibilities:

1. Use GCP custom metrics using client from google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-monitoring and stackdriver integration with Datadog
2. Use datadog agent deployed in the cloud and connect to it using Datadog StatsD client (Java, Python, Go)

---

1. Use GCP custom metrics
   https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics
   and datadog integration with GCP
   https://www.datadoghq.com/product/integrations/#cat-google-cloud

   ```java
   final MetricServiceClient client = MetricServiceClient.create();
   ProjectName name = ProjectName.of(projectId);

   MetricDescriptor descriptor = MetricDescriptor.newBuilder()
       .setType(metricType)
       .setDescription("This is a simple example of a custom metric.")
       .setMetricKind(MetricDescriptor.MetricKind.GAUGE)
       .setValueType(MetricDescriptor.ValueType.DOUBLE)
       .build();

   CreateMetricDescriptorRequest request = CreateMetricDescriptorRequest.newBuilder()
       .setName(name.toString())
       .setMetricDescriptor(descriptor)
       .build();

   client.createMetricDescriptor(request);
   ```
2. Use datadog statsd client, java one -
   https://github.com/DataDog/java-dogstatsd-client so you can deploy
   datadog agent on GCP and connect through it. Sample with kubernetes.
   https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup/kubernetes/#deploy-agent-daemonset

   ```java
   import com.timgroup.statsd.ServiceCheck;
   import com.timgroup.statsd.StatsDClient;
   import com.timgroup.statsd.NonBlockingStatsDClient;

   public class Foo {

     private static final StatsDClient statsd = new NonBlockingStatsDClient(
       "my.prefix",                          /* prefix to any stats; may be null or empty string */
       "statsd-host",                        /* common case: localhost */
       8125,                                 /* port */
       new String[] {"tag:value"}            /* Datadog extension: Constant tags, always applied */
     );

     public static final void main(String[] args) {
       statsd.incrementCounter("foo");
       statsd.recordGaugeValue("bar", 100);
       statsd.recordGaugeValue("baz", 0.01); /* DataDog extension: support for floating-point gauges */
       statsd.recordHistogramValue("qux", 15);     /* DataDog extension: histograms */
       statsd.recordHistogramValue("qux", 15.5);   /* ...also floating-point */
       statsd.recordDistributionValue("qux", 15);     /* DataDog extension: global distributions */
       statsd.recordDistributionValue("qux", 15.5);   /* ...also floating-point */

       ServiceCheck sc = ServiceCheck
             .builder()
             .withName("my.check.name")
             .withStatus(ServiceCheck.Status.OK)
             .build();
       statsd.serviceCheck(sc); /* Datadog extension: send service check status */

       /* Compatibility note: Unlike upstream statsd, DataDog expects execution times to be a
        * floating-point value in seconds, not a millisecond value. This library
        * does the conversion from ms to fractional seconds.
        */
       statsd.recordExecutionTime("bag", 25, "cluster:foo"); /* DataDog extension: cluster tag */
     }
   }
   ```

   datadog deployment.yaml for kubernetes

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: DaemonSet
   metadata:
     name: datadog-agent
   spec:
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: datadog-agent
         name: datadog-agent
       spec:
         serviceAccountName: datadog-agent
         containers:
         - image: datadog/agent:latest
           imagePullPolicy: Always
           name: datadog-agent
           ports:
             - containerPort: 8125
               # hostPort: 8125
               name: dogstatsdport
               protocol: UDP
             - containerPort: 8126
               # hostPort: 8126
               name: traceport
               protocol: TCP
           env:
             - name: DD_APM_ENABLED
               value: "true"
             - name: DD_API_KEY
               value: "<YOUR_API_KEY>"
             - name: DD_COLLECT_KUBERNETES_EVENTS
               value: "true"
             - name: DD_LEADER_ELECTION
               value: "true"
             - name: KUBERNETES
               value: "yes"
             - name: DD_KUBERNETES_KUBELET_HOST
               valueFrom:
                 fieldRef:
                   fieldPath: status.hostIP
           resources:
             requests:
               memory: "256Mi"
               cpu: "200m"
             limits:
               memory: "256Mi"
               cpu: "200m"
           volumeMounts:
             - name: dockersocket
               mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
             - name: procdir
               mountPath: /host/proc
               readOnly: true
             - name: cgroups
               mountPath: /host/sys/fs/cgroup
               readOnly: true
           livenessProbe:
             exec:
               command:
               - ./probe.sh
             initialDelaySeconds: 15
             periodSeconds: 5
         volumes:
           - hostPath:
               path: /var/run/docker.sock
             name: dockersocket
           - hostPath:
               path: /proc
             name: procdir
           - hostPath:
               path: /sys/fs/cgroup
             name: cgroups
   ```

Currently I'm investigating this so I'm not sure how to do this, yet.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20622016)

Comment: Added more details.